# Possibilities of Singleton instance getting deallocated automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am creating singleton instance as below:

```
+(MySingleton*)sharedInstance  {    
      static MySingleton sharedObject = nil;

      static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
         sharedObject = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedObject;  
}
```

What are the possibilities of `sharedObject` getting deallocated automatically?

How can I be sure that `sharedObject` will remain in memory until app is terminated?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As another answer rightly points out, this shared singleton will never be deallocated. There are two parts to answer "why", both of which come from the following line:

```
static MySingleton * sharedObject = nil;
```

First, `static`. `static`, when used inside of a function like this, modifies the *lifetime* of a variable, changing it from `automatic`, the implicit default, to `static`. This means that this variable exists for the entire lifetime of the program.

Second, this declaration makes sharedObject a *strong* reference. Variables in Objective-C are strong by default, but to be pedantic, you could have written:

```
static __strong MySingleton * sharedObject = nil;
```

So: we have a variable that lives for the entire duration of your program (`static`), and that maintains a strong reference to the object it represents (`__strong`). With these two pieces of information, plus the fact that you never change the object to which the variable points, you can deduce that `sharedObject` will never be deallocated.

Answer (score 3):

0 possibility. It will never be released, `static` keeps it with strong reference. In ARC world you can't just release something without first retaining it.

Comment: Since manual release and retain are forbidden in ARC, this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into one very dubious case where it can get released and cause unhappy problems, so while uncommon something to be careful of.

If a you pass its memory address a third party low level library ie. as user_data (or perhaps a low level c library you have created) and that library releases the memory.  You would not expect external libraries to release user_data you provide but that was the case with a web sockets c library I was using.

Answer (score -6):

`sharedObject` will be released after its included functions complete and after releasing contained blocks. so that, `dispatch_once` most probably releases running block after run it once. it means, it will be released just after called onece.

Comment: My concern is about any possibilities where singleton instance gets deallocated automatically?

Comment: The object will be deallocated when there are no strong references to it. The pointer `sharedObject` is a strong reference whose lifetime is the same as the entire program. This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: I know ARC. I just skipped "static" keyword. unless static, my saying is right